# firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification() doesn't work when user kill app

Tags: firebase, react-native, notifications, firebase-cloud-messaging

Below code is working when an app is open in the background. After killing app I am getting notifications but below code doesn't work. I want to redirect the user to a specific page when a user comes to the app through notification

`firebase.notifications().getInitialNotification()
    .then((notificationOpen) => {
         console.log("getInitialNotification");
    });`

Comment: did you get anything for this issue?